# is multi mapping in dapper care about the sqlstr`s column order?

Tags: orm, dapper

for example:

here is my pocos:

```
public class product
{
    public int productid { set; get; }
    public category category { set; get; }
    public string productname { set; get; }
}
```

also the category:

```
public class category
{
    public int categoryid { set; get; }
    public string categoryname { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

and the sqlstr:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, c.CategoryName, c.CategoryID,  c.Description 
from Products p inner join Categories c 
on p.CategoryID=c.CategoryID
```

if i choose "c.CategoryID" as splitOn. then c.CategoryName won`t be assigned, so i changed the order of column:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, c.CategoryID,  c.CategoryName, c.Description ...
```

this time  everything is ok.

am i misunderstand something, any help will be ok.

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I suspect you need to use `"CategoryID"` to split on, not `"c.CategoryID"`, as the results don't get to see the aliases (`c.`). But, to explain: the "split on" feature partitions a horizontal set of results into multiple pieces. For example, if we have:

```
Id    A    B    Id    C    D   Id    E    F
```

and we split on `"Id"`, then we get:

```
Id    A    B         |      Id    C    D        |       Id    E    F
```

(note that the "split" can be multiple different column names; it does not need to be the same thing each time)

So: within each horizontal partition - no, the order doesn't matter. But: if the "split" columns are positioned such that a column (`CategoryName`) ends up *in the wrong partition*, then yes, that matters. This behavior is demanded by the fact that column names *do not have to be unique* - so it can't just look for `CategoryName` - that could be unrelated; it needs to look for `CategoryName` *in the correct partition*.

In your specific example: move the column, or simply use `CategoryName` *as the split name* (basically, it just needs to know the first column in the partition).